# PHP find numbers in code and on second search skip first number?

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm currently working on a little code, because one of my colleges "destroyed" and xml document. I want to find all y="\d+" in a document and increase the digits by +3. My attempt is like this:

```
$path_to_file = 'testing.xml';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
if(preg_match('/y="\d+"/', $file_contents, $bef)){
    $length = count($bef);
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++){
        if($bef[$i]!=0){
            $file_contents = str_replace($bef[$i], 'y="'. $bef[$i]+3 .'"', $file_contents);
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
else{
    echo 'not found';   
}
```

It seems to find the first number in the document, but I can't figure out how to search for the 2. , 3. etc. Are there any resources you can give me where I can find a solution to my problem?

Edit:

To show what my problem was:

I have xml code like "< graphic-area y="125" x="324" width="bla" height="bla"> < /graphic-area>", etc. The code is later generated to a .pdf document. So my college didnt add the trim to the site, so every y property, except y="0" is 3 mm too low. And we have 60+ pages with lets say 400+ areas with y properties. So I needed a php code to get the y properties fixed. 
This solution works fine, WITHOUT '25.2' numbers, so without numbers with a dot. The solution for this is to just use two different patterns and then get the number before the dot and increase it. Here is the code from the best answer without the "253.2232" solution.

```
$path_to_file = 'testing.xml';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

$pattern = '/y="(\d+)"/';
$new_contents = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'add_three', $file_contents);

file_put_contents($path_to_file,$new_contents);

function add_three($matches){
    return 'y="' . (3 + (int)$matches[1]) . '"';
}
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: You could use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Comment: This should really be done with a proper XML library like SimpleXML, rather than a regular expression. Can you post a small snippet of the XML you need to process?

Comment: `preg_match` allows you to specify an offset from where it should start the search. But I think using `preg_replace_callback` would make this easier …

Comment: Hey guys, solution is found! preg_replace_callback works just fine! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path_to_file = 'testing.xml';
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);

$pattern = '/y="(\d+\.?\d*)"/'; // Optional dot follower by optional digits
$new_contents = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'add_three', $file_contents);

file_put_contents($path_to_file,$new_contents);

function add_three($matches){
    return 'y="' . (3 + (float)$matches[1]) . '"'; // Cast to float not int, since we can do floats too
}
```

This will call `add_three` to ever match in the document.

Comment: Perfect! Works just fine. Now comes one problem. There are some y="215.2" numbers. Where do I differentiate my numbers? Can I just use two different patterns? One for simple 215 numbers and one for "215.2" numbers?

Comment: I think this is a stupid question as it should work just fine :D

Comment: One minor fix for your code: In the add three function you used 'y="' + .... Which should be 'y="' . (3 ,etc. (. instead of +)

Comment: @Fredrik Good eye. Could my you explain how you intend to treat floats differently? If the behaviour is unchanged it's a minor edit, if you're doing something more difficult I suggest making two functions and two replacements.

Comment: Yes I think I will need two replacements. Or is it possible with php to determine if its a float and not an integer and add the +3 to a float? Like if it says "252.1" +3 the sum will be "255.1"?

Comment: @FrederikWitte Do you want to check my edit, see if that covers your needs?

Comment: Hey, cant check right now, I will tell you tomorrow! Thank you for the fast responses

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_match_all` since `preg_match` only returns `1`, `0` or `false`.

As such:

```
if (preg_match_all('/y="\d+"/', $file_contents, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // $match will contain information about the current match
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, nice start, but I think this is too complex, the solution from scragar is working just fine :-)!